# how to play multiple songs in background in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i want to play songs in background without click for next song , songs will change in background and play next song in background .i search this link for play song in background :  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/

but from this link  only we play one song in background . but i required play multiple songs in background like as music player .

is there any way to play multiple songs in background please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when the song has finished to play you should use AVAudioPlayer Delegate!

When the song finishes to play you can change to the next song in method:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

In this method you should remove your current player and init new player with new song.